# Cannot dismiss the alert dialog box in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view

I have an issue in dissmissing the alertdialog box which is customized. That is it is having a customized view that contains two buttons one is for db operation and other for loading another activity.I want to dissmiss the dialog box after the db action performed. But now i cant declare any command like `dialog.dismiss()` or `cancel()` or `finish()` please somebody help me to fix this.

**My Class**

```
  @Override
   protected boolean onTap(int index) {
     OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);
     final String  title= item.getTitle();
     final String snippet= item.getSnippet();
     AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
     if(title.equalsIgnoreCase("Your Location")){
     dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
     dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
     dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
     }
     else if(title.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
     LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
     layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

     final Button park_button = new Button(context);
     park_button.setHint("Park here");
   //  park_button.setBackgroundResource();
     layout.addView(park_button);
     park_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("parkbutton:Clicked");
            // Delete DB Values
            int count = db.getDatasCount();
            for(int i = 0;i<count;i++){
                db.deleteValues(i);
            }
            //latitude & longtitude (string)
               String latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
               String longtitude = String.valueOf(lon);
               Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
               db.addData(new Datas(latitude, longtitude));
              // Toast.makeText(context, "Lat: " + lat + ", Lon: "+lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Reading DB Data
               Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all Values...");
               List<Datas> datas = db.getAllDatas();       

               for (Datas dat : datas) {
                   String log = "Id: "+dat.getID()+" ,Latitude: " + dat.getlat() + " ,Longtitude: " + dat.getlon();
                       // Writing DB data to log
               Log.d("DB Data: ", log);
           }
            Intent f = new Intent(context,MainTabActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(f);
        }
    });


     final Button know_more_button = new Button(context);
     know_more_button.setHint("Know more");
     //  park_button.setBackgroundResource();
     layout.addView(know_more_button);
     know_more_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor =prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("KEY_REFERENCE", snippet);
            editor.commit();                

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SinglePlaceActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     dialog.setView(layout);
     dialog.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
     }
     dialog.show();
     return true;
   }

   public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
      mapOverlays.add(overlay);
   }

   public void populateNow(){
       this.populate();
   }

}
```

Comment: Try to show a dialog without setting content view `dialog.setView(layout);`

Comment: But i need to set two buttons inside the view in addition to this positive and negative button

Comment: So the issue is that you cannot hide a dialog from a click listener of a button from your custom layout. Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, to explain how to get the behavior you want, I'll need you to rename your AlertDialog.Builder instance, currently named **dialog**, to **builder**. It's not accurately named and will help you understand my approach to solving your problem. So this line:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
```

would turn into:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
```

From there, you'll need to:

1. Create a **final** reference to the AlertDialog instance that is returned to you when you call show() - and call *it* **dialog**.
2. Next, move the button click listeners you've set up down beneath where you call show() on the builder.
3. Finally, reference the **dialog** var I had you create, and call dismiss() on that.

See code below:

```
// ... original code here (right before the end of your onTap main method)
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show(); // this line used to be "dialog.show();"
know_more_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // ... original code here
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
// ... for the other button, do the same
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to extend DialogFragment if it is acceptable (you need to extend your activity from FragmentActivity).

```
public static class Dialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
        btn.setText("dismiss");

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        b.setView(btn);
        b.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        return b.create();
    }
}
```

You can show dialog in this way (android.support.v4 is used):

```
new Dialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Also you need establish [communication](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) between dialog and activity.

Comment: you can achieve this, if your `context` member will be FragmentActivity. Or you can expose an interface with method `onOverlayItemTapped(Item item)` and process tap event in activity (instead of ItemizedOverlay)

Answer (score 0):

do this

`final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);`

not 
`AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);`

Comment: An explanation as to why you need to do that is always useful to help understanding of an answer

Comment: here i am setting two buttons in a layout and that view is again sticking into this alert dialog box so there are two more buttons besides of this positive button and negative buttons from the first button click i need to perform some db operations and i did it but after this operation i cannot dismiss the dialog cause of dialog.dissmiss() is not getting to the button click

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Add .create when creating AlertDialog Builder.

```
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext()).create()
```

Once this is done. dismiss() function is exposed with dialogBuilder